# Buffer Overflow add bytes over 0x7E to stack

Tags: c, hex, overflow, buffer

I've been experimenting with buffer overflows by having a c program which takes a string as an argument. It then (I think? not very familiar with the vulnerability in question) calls strcpy to a string of 64 length without checking the length of the argument string, so what's over my value of 64 will overwrite other parts of the stack.

I believe each character in question is converted to its hex counterpart in ASCII, and then written to the stack. However, as ASCII only goes up to 7E, how would someone get any values between 7F and 9F onto the stack?

I'm aware of the fact that I don't really understand the topic, and if anyone would like to clarify what exactly is going on in their answer, that would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Who said you cannot pass values higher than `0x7E` for characters?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *p = argv[1];
    unsigned char c;

    if (argc < 2) return 1;

    while ((c = *p++))
    {
        printf("%02x\n", (unsigned int) c);
    }
}
```

See we can pass character values higher than `0x7E` in the `argv[1]` string:

```
$ ./tst $(echo -ne "\xAB\xCD\xEF\xFF")
ab
cd
ef
ff
$
```

Answer (score 0):

In C a `char` is actually a byte and can therefore take 255 (`0xFF`) values. While (7 bit-)ASCII will let you display bytes between `0x20` and `0x7E` (not counting extended (8 bit-)ASCII) you can still provide any value between 0 and 255 to a C `char`.

As to what happens when you push more bytes on the stack than is expected, only God knows (i.e. it is undefined), and you should really not do it. Hint: use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/).

Comment: I know it's a huge security vulnerability, and I know about strncpy(specify amount to copy, etc. etc.). I'm just trying to do this for the sake of it, seeing how to edit variables and how the stack works a little better.